# How can I get the correct output for a system of equations symbolically?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve a system of equations symbolically and printing out the the corresponding equations for each solved variables. Unfortunately when I put the 3 variables that I want to solve for it gives me this error:
eq, cov = unrad(f)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

But if I put only one variable it returns false. By the way, the equation is the Lagrange multiplier that I am trying to obtain a solution for.

I have tried to use different solvers to see if there is a suitable one but only nonlinsolve seems to be suitable because the equation is nonlinear.

```
    from sympy import Symbol, symbols,Eq
    from sympy.abc import x, y,z,phi
    from sympy.plotting import plot
    from sympy import expand, pprint,simplify,pi,solve,sqrt
    from sympy import*
    from sympy import solve, Poly, Eq, Function, exp

    V1, V2 ,L, F,Lamb ,D1,D2= symbols('V1 V2 L F Lamb D1 D2')

    Icom = (V1/V2)*((3/2)*D1**2 -D1**3) + (V2/V1)*((3/2)*D2**2 - D2**3)
    A = (sqrt(V1*V2))/(2*L*F*sqrt(2))
    B = (3/2)*(D1**2 + D2**2)
    C = -3*(D1 + D2)+2
    D = 3*(D1+D2)*phi
    E = (-3/2)*(D1**2 +D2**2)*phi
    F1 = -3*phi +3*phi**2/2 -phi**3/2
    #objective 
    Cu = A*(Icom +B+C+D+E+F1)**(1/2)


    # Constraint 
    P0 = (V1*V2)* (-((D1**2) + (D2**2)-2) + 2*(D1+D2) +phi*(2-phi))/(8*L*F)


    L = Cu + Lamb *(P0)
    print('###########################################################')
    dL_D1 = Eq((diff(L,D1))) # derivative of L with respect to D1
    pprint(dL_D1)
    dL_D2 = Eq(diff(L,D2)) #derivative of L with respect to D2
    pprint(Eq(dL_D2))
    dL_Phi = Eq(diff(L,phi)) # derivative of L with respect to phi
    pprint(Eq(dL_Phi))
    dL_dlambda = Eq(diff(L,Lamb)) # derivative of L with respect to lambda
    pprint(Eq(dL_dlambda))
    system = nonlinsolve([dL_D1, dL_D2, dL_Phi,dL_dlambda],(D1,D2,phi)) #% build the system of equations
    pprint(system)
    print('------------------------------------------------------')
```

The expected outcome is to have a symbolic solution for D1,D2 and phi

Here is one of the error message that I got
eq, cov = unrad(f) TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but it seems your expressions involve rational numbers and square roots. You should use `Rational` to indicate them, instead of `/` ([documentation link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers))

Comment: Here is a complete list of the error messages:   
  File "C:\Users\JPG\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py", line 728, in _solve_radical
    eq, cov = unrad(f)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug in SymPy 1.4. Running with latest master I get this as the output:

```
⎧⎛       _____________________________       ⎞  ⎛   _____________________________           ⎞⎫
⎨⎜      ╱     2           2                  ⎟  ⎜  ╱     2           2                      ⎟⎬
⎩⎝1 - ╲╱  - D₂  + 2⋅D₂ - φ  + 2⋅φ + 3 , D₂, φ⎠, ⎝╲╱  - D₂  + 2⋅D₂ - φ  + 2⋅φ + 3  + 1, D₂, φ⎠⎭
```

This is the form for an underdetermined system where D2 and phi can be anything but D1 can be determined in terms of the other two.

Does that look correct to you?

Comment: In the answer, I am expecting to see the other variables also such as V1 and V2.  D1 should be a function of D2,phi, V1 and V2; D2 should be a function of D1 ,phi, V1 and  V2 and phi should a function of D1,D2,V1 and V2 as well.  Thank you so much for taking a look at it, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Basically the goal is to find the expression for D1, D2 and phi that minimizes the objective function (cu) so I am using Lagrange multiplier to solve for that.

Comment: Okay so why are you solving 4 equations for 3 unknowns?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out . Now I have changed it to 3 equations with 4 unknown which is the right set up it did run without error. But in other to make sense of the answers I would to be able to print each unknown separately not as a system so I can analyze it because I have a good idea of what the answer will look like. Any suggestions will be very appreciated. Here the changes that I made  system = nonlinsolve([dL_D1, dL_D2, dL_Phi],(D1,D2,phi,Lamb)) 
pprint(system).

Comment: As a clarification, this is what I wanted to do but it gave an error message     print( "D1 = ", (system[D1]).factor())

TypeError: 'FiniteSet' object is not subscriptablealso.print( "D1 = ", (system[D1]).factor())
print( "\\begin{array}{rcl}")
print ("D1 & = & %s \\\\" % latex((system[D1]).factor()))
print ("\\end{array}")